# How to require/import anime js once installed in npm

Tags: javascript, express, anime.js

Installed anime js as dependency to my package.json its visible there with version 3.0.1.

installed via npm

created folder and js file in public.
created a simple listener on a div not related to anime js, this works as i also refence to this script in my ejs file.

when i write an animation i get either anime reference error to that.

how i can import/require animeJS and bodymovin so i can use it in the desired files?
can someone show me a best practise?

created folder and js file in public.
created a simple listener on a div not related to anime js, this works as i also refence to this script in my ejs file.

Comment: You might need to provide some more details on your environment. Are you just using plain JS+HTML, or do you have a package management system in place, i.e. webpack/grunt/gulp, etc.

Comment: hi, im running on express js and just installed anime js via npm package. i know i cound simply add the cdn to the public file html, but actually there is no actual version cdn available.

i thought i could just require the package and use it but it seems that this is not the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your html file/layout file. if you want to use in ejs. 
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js"></script>`

Comment: hi, thx for that i know i could add the cdn to the script. the fact is that anime.js is now on version 3 and the cdn still runs on version 2.

Comment: my suggestion is download version 3 from their git repo and add it manually in index.html or layout.ejs file